# Is there an api to create a Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, sdk

Is there an api that can be used to create a crystal report programmatically? I have reports written in Powerbuilder that we need to convert to Crystal and I would like to automate the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal does have a report creation API, but I believe you have to have a license to their report server product to use it> I tried to find a link to this info on their site, but it is pretty well hidden.

Comment: A lot of things Crystal have been pretty well hidden since SAP bought them. Their site integration with Business Objects' site sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Review the [Crystal Reports SDK](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/whgdata/whlstt0.htm#3615).  There are COM, .Net, and Java 'flavors'.

For an example of converting an RPT file to XML, review this Google Code project: [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)

Answer (score 0):

For .NET based languages, there's a [Crystal Reports SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225335(v=vs.90).aspx) available from Microsoft. They expose the object model and an SDK to create Crystal Report files.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at http://crystalreports.co.uk/developer-zone/ and select the appropriate platform (Java or .NET) and this will take you to a list of links into the SAP website.

The list is maintained by the one of the partners so should be up to date.